# Get values list from a key in Dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I wrote the code below to get all the values from a dictionary which has the given key.

```
        Dictionary<string,string> _dictionary;

        public List<string> GetValuesUsingKey(string key)
        {
            List<string> outp = new List<string>();
            foreach(var d in _dictionary)
            {
                if (d.Key == key)
                {
                    outp.Add(d.Value);
                }
            }
            return outp;
        }
```

is there a simpler way to achieve this result using LINQ?

**Update :**

it turned out that i was mislearned about Dictionaries, i though i could use multiple values for a single key but i was wrong

Comment: What is `_dictionary`? If it really is a `Dictionary<string,string>`, the keys are unique, meaning there is at max 1 element per key. So the most efficient way is simply `_dictinoary[key]`.

Comment: @René but that might throw, I'd recommend `TryGetValue(string key)`.

Comment: So it means in my case i should use something like List<Tuple<string,string>> ? @RenéVogt

Comment: It seems possible that you wanted something like a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`, but we can't tell because we don't know what kind fo data you want to store here.

Comment: @alix54 why do you think it is list ? It would be great if you could provide more information on what you are trying to accomplish here. From what is given, there would be only one element per key, so you do not require list here

Comment: @RenéVogt my data is categorized, something like 4 keys and 50 values

Comment: @alix54 if that's the case, what you would need is Dictionary<string,List<string>>

Comment: @AnuViswan thanks for the suggestion, sorry for my mislearning of Dictionaries

Comment: If your data has multiple entries for the same key, you can use an `ILookup<TKey, TElement` which can be created by calling Linq's `ToLookup`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) is a one to one map, you cannot have multiple values for a given key.

[ILookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netframework-4.8) on the other hand supports this scenario, as well as null keys:

```
using System.Linq;

class Element
{
    public string Key { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
    ...
}

IEnumerable<Element> elements = ...
ILookup<string, string> lookup = elements.ToLookup(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

and then to get your result:

```
List<string> outp = lookup[key].ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

A key in a `Dictionary` is guaranteed to be unique, so there's no need to return a `List`.

```cs
public string GetValueUsingKey(string key)
{
  bool isKeyPresent = _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var output);
  return isKeyPresent ? output : _YOUR_DEFAULT_BEHAVIOUR_;
}
```

The big advantage of a `Dictionary` is that the time complexity for insertion and retrieval of values using the key is `O(1)`; if you cycle through all the `KeyValuePair` it contains you completely nullify the purpose of using a `Dictionary` as it would make the retrieval `O(n)`!